# Using Regexp_extract returns error column does not exist in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following SQL query:

```
select unique_product_id from inventory where
REGEXP_EXTRACT(unique_product_id, "[^-]*$");
```

but I get the error: `column "[^-]*$" does not exist`

`[^-]*$` is the regex expression that matches everything after a "-". My unique_product_id column is of the format: `productName-productID` so I am trying to extract productID.

I'm pretty sure I'm following this example exactly:
https://docs.data.world/documentation/sql/reference/functions/regexp_extract.html

Any help as to waht I'm doing wrong would be much apprecaited.
Thanks

Comment: I just updated to include the DBMS. Thanks

Comment: If you are using Postgres, then why are you not reading the [Postgres manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions.html)? In SQL string constants needs to be enclosed in single quotes, i.e. `'[^-]*$'` - but Postgres does not have a `regexp_extract()` function. You need to use `substring(... from ..)`

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm far from an expert here and didn't realize teh problem was specific to postgres.

Comment: You will need to provide more information on what you want to achieve. Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables.